# Can we sort a Set by keys and values in Map?

Tags: java, collections

i have a class Car representing name and IDs of cars:

```
public class Car {
String name;
int ID;
}
```

and another class representing races in which i need to sort the cars by their order in race:

```
public class Race {
private Set<Car> cars = new TreeSet<>();
private Map<Integer, Integer> races = new TreeMap<>();//key represents the order in race, value represents the ID of a car, so i need to sort cars by the keys in races
...
public Collection getSortedCars() { ??? }
}
```

-any ideas how to get sorted cars? thanks much

EDIT: Im sorry, i used very bad example with values, so heres it with identifiers, i hope you get what i need..

Comment: It's unclear what the meaning of the integers in the map are, or how they relate to the Car record.  If you wish to subsequently sort a set of objects once created, you would create a new TreeSet with an explicit comparator that uses the race data to sort individual car records.

Answer (score 3):

I would *not* do this with a SortedSet, even [though a custom Comparator could be used](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/). The reason is because the races could be modified and thus *invalidate* any structure inside the TreeSet making the behavior "unpredictable".

Instead, I would make `getSortedCars` first get a sequence (e.g. a List) from the Set, and then sort and return such a sequence.

The actual sorting is "trivial" with [Collections.sort](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29) and a custom [Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) as this is really a "sort by" operation, for instance:

```
class CompareCarsByWins implements Comparator<Car> {
    Map<Car,Integer> wins;

    public CompareCarsByWins(Map<Car,Integer> wins) {
        this.wins = wins;
    }

    public int compareTo (Car a, Car b) {
        // Actual code should handle "not found" cars as appropriate
        int winsA = wins.get(a);
        int winsB = wins.get(b);
        if (winsA == winsB) {
            // Tie, uhm, let's .. choose by name
            return a.getName().compareTo(b.getName());
        } else {
            // Sort most wins first
            return winsB - winsA;
        }
    }
    // ..
}

// Usage:
List<Car> results = new ArrayList<Car>(cars);
Collections.sort(results, new CompareCarsByWins(races));
```

Comment: This is the correct answer, +1.  Just a minor point though - I would name the `Comparator` class in a way that indicates what sort order it implements.  So instead of `CompareCars`, maybe `CarsByNumberOfWins` would be a better name for this `Comparator`.  That way, if you end up with several different comparators for the `Car` class, it's clear which is which.

Comment: Hey, this is not working, because my Map is <Integer, Integer> and not <Car, Integer> so its not working for me :/

Comment: @CharlieHarper I'm sure you can modify this very easily so that it looks up the car's ID in the map, not the car itself.