# How do you sort a hash map table with values and keys in Java

Tags: java, sorting, hashmap

How do you sort out a hash maps numerically and then alphabetically ?
input:

```
anna , 1
jane , 2
amy  , 3
```

required output:

```
amy  , 3
anna , 1
jane , 2
```

`Map<String, Integer> myDictionary = new HashMap<String, Integer>();`

This is how i sort it out atm but it only sorts it alphabetically

```
Set<String> sorted = new TreeSet<String>(); 

sorted.addAll(myDictionary.keySet());

for(String key: sorted){

    System.out.println(key  + " -" + myDictionary.get(key));

}
```

Comment: A previous answer of mine: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22672888/2864740 - 1) define a `Comparator`, 2) Don't use a Set for this, even if a SortedSet. (It even has an example of "sort by .. then by ..", see how the names are also compared in case of a tie on wins.)

Comment: Also, ref. perhaps: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3074324/2864740

Comment: You don't sort a HashMap.  You can sort the keys of the HashMap and then access the HashMap by sorted key, or you can use a LinkedHashMap and somehow get your entries into the desired order.  But a standard Map or Set has no defined order.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the Map into a List, sort the List by Comparator and put the sorted list back to a Map.

Look into this for reference [Sort a Map by Values](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-sort-a-map-in-java/)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a rough sketch of how you'd probably want to work with

```
class Person 
{
   public String name;
   public int point;
   //others methods
}
class SortName implements Comparator<Person>
{
   public int compare(Person one, Person two)
   {return comparison of name}
}

class SortPoint implements Comparator<Person>
{
   public int compare(Person one, Person two)
   {return comparison of point}
}

//usage
List.sort(person, new SortName());
```